# How to properly post url in android with java using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, url, http-post, httpurlconnection

I try to use HttpURLConnection to send a post request to my local (xampp) server with an url like this `http://xxx.xxx.0.3/Company/index.php/booking/c200/p-205/2025-02-09 8:2` , the server php file take param in url and send data to mysql database .

The url works fine on postman agent , and even another get method request works smooth in the android application .

Yet when i try the post method with following code :

```
public void postOrder() {
        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        Thread t = new Thread( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                try {
                    String link = "http://xxx.xxx.0.3/Company/index.php/booking/c200/p-205/2025-02-09 8:2";
                    URL url = new URL(link);
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /*ms*/);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /*ms*/);
                    conn.connect();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("HTTP error: ", e.toString());
                }
                finally {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
            }
        } );
        t.start();
}
```

It never sent the url and thus no data is stored to database .

And with 6 hours of trial and error , google and searching , i added this line of code :

```
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
```

And it finally works .
Please answer me why it only works after adding this line of code , what does it do ? I thought the url is triggered right after `conn.connect();`

Comment: Javadocs? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect()

Comment: I would not call that a post request when the parameters are in the url. Moreover you are posting nothing. It's not a get request either.

Comment: I have change the title into post an URL , hope it dissolves the confusion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `connect()` only connects, but it doesn't send anything yet. Call `getResponseCode()` to force the request to be sent. That method is safer than `getInputStream()` which will throw an exception if the response is not a 2xx (in which case you'd need `getErrorStream()`).